# Django - automatically create a model instance when another model instance is created

Tags: django

I have an overrided User model and a Cart model. I expect that a Cart model instance is created automatically once a User model instance is created. I am trying to pass the newly registered user into the `get_queryset` method, but no idea how to do it. Are there any other better ways of doing this? It's because I may need to do the same thing for other models unlike the User model which has a form that can pass values to the `get_queryset` method.

**account/models.py:**

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email + '_cart'
```

**account/views.py:**

```
class RegisterView(generic.CreateView):
    template_name = 'account/register.html'
    form_class = RegisterForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('book:home')

    def get_queryset(self):
        sign_up = self.request.POST.get('register')
        if sign_up:
            c = Cart.objects.create(user=???)
            c.save()
```

**account/templates/account/register.html:**

```
<form name="register" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Sign Up">
</form>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a [Django `post_save` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/signals/#post-save) hooked up to the `User` model.

See the [signals tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/) for more information.

Answer (score 23):

**Method-1**: Use Django's **`post_save`** signal (as @AKX said)

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


@receiver(post_save, sender=get_user_model())
def create_user_cart(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Cart.objects.create(user=instance)
```

**Method-2**: Override the  **`save()`** method of your ***User model*** or ***extended Usermodel***

```
class MyUserModel(....):
    # your code
    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        created = not self.pk
        super().save(*args,**kwargs)
        if created:
            Cart.objects.create(user=self)
```

Comment: Hello @JPG, i would like to know what is this created = not self.pk doing! i am little bit confused in here, this method worked for me but i would like to know how is this code actually working!

Comment: @LuisRodriguez `self.pk` will be **`None`** for instances that are going to be created.

Comment: @LuisRodriguez `pk` is Django's reliable shortcut for the [primary key field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/#the-pk-lookup-shortcut). Basically what the code is doing checking if the primary key was set before save, if so this is a new object creation, otherwise it is an update.

Answer (score 2):

override save method, signals are harder to read/track through multiple files and are synchronous.

https://lincolnloop.com/blog/django-anti-patterns-signals/

```
class Pizza(models.Model):
    has_pepperoni = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        created = self.pk is None
        super(Pizza, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if created and self.has_pepperoni:
            ToppingSales.objects.filter(name='pepperoni').update(
                units_sold=F('units_sold') + 1)           


class ToppingSales(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    units_sold = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the modern ways (as per the docs) are to do this during a create() class method or to write a custom manager.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/instances/